# IntelliJ Idea - How to optimize imports for a custom scope

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

Is there an option in IntelliJ Idea 15.0.3 to optimize the imports in all files of a custom scope or matching a file name pattern?

The dialog for "Code | Optimize imports" does not have such an option.
The dialog for "Code | Reformat Code" has an option to restrict the operation to some scope or file mask but it also reformats code that does not match the code style, which I do not want.

Is there another option (maybe in some plugin?) or a simple workaround to just optimize the imports of some files of a certain type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea 15.0.3 does not have such an option.

Here's a very old request for this feature: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5372

I now wrote a custom plugin for this purpose: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8188